# Run videolan from browser

Tags: browser, vlc, hta

I'm trying to launch VideoLan (or the default local video player) from the browser, but **not embedded in it**.

The idea is to create a small movie list with an .hta file (or similar). I want to run it, see the movie list and select the one I want to play. But all I need is that particular movie to be played locally, out of the browser; just the same as me double clicking on the file.

Is this difficult?

I'm open to any answer, not just ".hta" kind. I'd like my app to run on a browser, but it's OK to use any other platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `shell.run` to execute the video(the following codes are JScript):

```
 shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell") ;
 shell.run('"C:\\path\\to\\video.mp4"');
```

...what will open the video with the default-player

to open it with VLC use:

```
shell.run('"C:\\path\\to\vlc.exe" "C:\\path\\to\\video.mp4"');
```

Comment: It worked! But only when I place the file in the main folder (C:). It seems to have problems with longer paths, even without spaces. Any idea? Maybe there's a better way to do this; I don't mind trying any alternative to .hta files...

Comment: I've edited my answer, note the quotes, wrap the complete command with single-quotes and the pathes with double-quotes. Also check the path, when the files(vlc.exe or the video ) are placed in special folders(e.g. Desktop,Users,Program Files) the name of this folder displayed in windows-explorer may differ from the real folder-name. You must use the correct folder-name in the filesystem(may be seen via file->properties), not the alias used in the explorer.

Comment: Sorry Dr. Molle, but it didn't work this way. Nevertheless, I found out something interesting: If I create a Shortcut in the root directory (C:) -pointing to the file I want to open-, it works perfectly. I write the path to the shortcut and that's all. It may not be a clean solution, but maybe I can modify the shotcut's destiny file everytime I want to open a certain one (and of course creating the shortcut if it doesn't exist).